# CefAuthCallback::Continue() how to call it outside the GetAuthCredentials method

Tags: c++, chromium-embedded

I'm using CEF3 writing an application in C++. I need to authenticate to a https page and I use CefRequestHandler::GetAuthCredentials

```
bool GetAuthCredentials( CefRefPtr< CefBrowser > browser, CefRefPtr< CefFrame > frame, bool isProxy, const CefString& host, int port, const CefString& realm, const CefString& scheme, CefRefPtr< CefAuthCallback > callback );
```

According to the documentation:

> Return true to continue the request and call CefAuthCallback::Continue() either in this method or at a later time when the authentication information is available. Return false to cancel the request immediately.

I've tried saving the CefAuthCallback pointer to use it later but I get a crash as soon as I try to call Continue with it.

Any example or idea how to call Continue from outside the GetAuthCredentials method?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a thread issue or an incorrect caching of CefAuthCallback.

What I have done in my (Windows) implementation is this.
0. *GetAuthCredentials* is called on IO thread.
1. Cached all the *GetAuthCredentials* arguments into a structure

```
struct auth_credentials_param_t {
    CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser;
    bool isProxy;
    CefString host;
    int port;
    CefString realm;
    CefString scheme;
    CefRefPtr<CefAuthCallback> auth_callback;
    bool result;
    auth_credentials_param_t(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser, 
        bool isProxy, 
        const CefString& host, int port,
        const CefString& realm, const CefString& scheme, 
        CefRefPtr<CefAuthCallback> auth_callback) 
        : browser(browser)
        , isProxy(isProxy)
        , host(host)
        , port(port)
        , realm(realm)
        , scheme(scheme)
        , auth_callback(auth_callback)
        , result(false) {
    }
};
```

2. Implementation of *GetAuthCredentials* is this:

   ```
   std::unique_ptr<auth_credentials_param_t> acp(
       new auth_credentials_param_t(
       browser, 
       isProxy, host, port, realm, scheme, 
       callback));
   m_pMainWindow->HandleAuthCredentials(
       acp.release());
   return true;
   ```

m_pMainWindow is, as name says, the main window implementation.
(We are still on the IO thread).

3. The *MainWindow* class have two members (first is the actual call from client handler, the second is just a IO-to-UI thread task callback - see below):

   ```
   void HandleAuthCredentials(
       auth_credentials_param_t* acp);
   static void CBHandleAuthCredentials(
       MainWindow* pMW, 
       auth_credentials_param_t* acp);
   ```

which are implemented like this (see below). 
MainWindow::HandleAuthCredentials need to run on the UI thread, so first time is called from IO thread, and when thread != UI, repost the call to UI thread using *CefPostTask*. *CBHandleAuthCredentials* just calls *HandleAuthCredentials*, this time in UI thread.

```
    void MainWindow::CBHandleAuthCredentials(
        MainWindow* pMW, 
        auth_credentials_param_t* acp)
    {
        pMW->HandleAuthCredentials(acp);
    }

    void MainWindow::HandleAuthCredentials(
        auth_credentials_param_t* acp_ptr
    ) {
        if(this == nullptr) {
            return; }

        std::unique_ptr<auth_credentials_param_t> acp(acp_ptr);
        if(!acp.get()) {
            return; }

        if(!CefCurrentlyOn(TID_UI)) {
            CefPostTask(
                TID_UI, 
                base::Bind(
                    &MainWindow::CBHandleAuthCredentials, 
                    this, 
                    acp.release()
                )
            );        
            return; }

        CEF_REQUIRE_UI_THREAD();

        // here follows the logic of authentication
        // for example, have an authentication cache
        // and if user, pass and host matches, continue, else present an 
        // authentication dialog to the user

        //
        // ... code omitted for brevity
        //

        // browser_auth_info_t is a wrapper structure containing 
        // host, port, realm, scheme, user, password, 
        // remember flag, and browser identifier
        // m_AuthCache is a collection of browser_auth_info_t
        // 
        std::vector<browser_auth_info_t> entries;
        if(m_AuthCache.findAuthCacheEntries(sTarget, entries)) {
            // if multiple (even this should not happen), pick first
            std::wstring user = entries[0].user();
            std::wstring pass = entries[0].pass();

            // mark this entry as active
            browser_auth_info_t entry = entries[0];
            m_AuthCache.markEntryAsActive(entry);

            //  inform authentication to continue
            CefString username = user;
            CefString password = pass;
            acp->auth_callback->Continue(user, pass);
            acp->result = true;       
        }
        else {
            //  we cannot supply credentials from cache
            //  display logon dialog

            browser_auth_info_t bi(
                acp->browser->GetIdentifier(), 
                acp->host.ToWString(), 
                acp->port, 
                acp->realm.ToWString(), 
                acp->scheme.ToWString());

            std::wstring sUser;
            std::wstring sPass;
            bool remember = false;

            INT_PTR result = CDlgAuth::Display(g_hUiTxtInstance, 
                get_hwnd(), &bi, sUser, sPass, remember);
            if(result != IDOK) {
                //  user canceled the authentication dialog
                acp->result = false;
                acp->auth_callback->Cancel();
                break;
            }
            else {
                //  user provided auth info

                //  update the cache with provided credentials
                bi.update(sUser, sPass, remember);
                m_AuthCache.updateEntryPassword(&bi);

                //  inform authentication to continue
                CefString username = sUser;
                CefString password = sPass;
                acp->auth_callback->Continue(username, password);

                acp->result = true;
                break;
            }
        }
```